# OSX -- How to define save-file-as that opens a directory tree window

Tags: emacs

I need some assistance, please, defining a save-as function that opens a directory tree instead of just giving me a path in the status bar . . .  Specifically, `ns-popup-save-panel` is not recognized by the current version of emacs.  I am looking for something similar to `write-file filename &optional confirm`. I have tried different combinations, but I still cannot get the pop-up menu save-file directory tree.  I already have the keyboard shortcut figured out.  Emacs complains of void variables when I try to insert `write-file filename &optional confirm`.  Just plain old `write-file` or `save-buffer` doesn't open the directory listing.

```
(defun mac-key-save-file-as (&optional filename)
"Save buffer to a file, selecting file by dialog.
Displays sheet.  File is saved once user has dismissed sheet."
    (interactive)
   (ns-popup-save-panel "Select File to Save Buffer" default-directory (if buffer-file-name (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name) "Untitled"))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M-x ns RET

This brings up a list of all commands begging with ns-

The code cited in the question is from Aquamacs 2.4.

The newest version of Emacs (24.3) built from source uses different names.  In this particular case, the new name is `ns-write-file-using-panel`.